# How to join two dataframes and keep only those rows of data that appear in both data frames and then create a histogram using the index as the ylabel

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, matplotlib

I need to join two dataframes called 'strava' and 'cheetah' so that only those rows of data that appear in both dataframes are kept. so that we have complete data in every row.
I then have to look at the distributions for some key variables: 'time, distance, average speed, average power and TSS' and see if the distributions are normal or skewed.

I have attempted to join the two dataframes and getting rid of the nan values:

```
df = strava.join(cheetah,how='inner').dropna()
```

[Output1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l3kNh.png)

> Question1: Is this how you're supposed to join the two dataframes so
>   that only those rows of data appear in both dataframes are kept?

I then created a dataframe containing only the columns that I want to look at:

```
df1 = df[['elapsed_time','distance','Average Speed','Average Power','TSS']]
df1.head()
```

[Output2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VwQoo.png)

I then wanted to observe the distributions on these columns by creating a histogram using df1 as the x label and the indices of df1(the datetimes) as the ylabel.

```
cols = df1.columns.tolist()
plt.hist(cols,density=True,bins=30)
plt.ylabel(?)
```

> Question 2: My problem is that I do not know what to put as the
>   ylabel.. how do I reference the index? I believe that the indices of
>   the dataframes are datetimeindex objects, so how would I plot them on
>   the y-label?

P.S. Sorry if this question format is confusing, I am new to stackoverflow and am trying my best to create good questions so I dont get banned from asking.

Comment: `df1.columns` is a list of strings. It does not make sense to plot a histogram of unique strings (each will just occur once anyways).